# Fisher Information Matrix change parameterization

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, parameter-estimation, parametrization, fisher-information

Lets say I have a $2 \times 2$ Fisher information matrix $\mathbf{I}_{\mathbf{a}}$ of the parameter vector $\mathbf{a}$. I want to transform this matrix to find the Fisher information $I_b$ of a scalar parameter $b$, which can be expressed by a function of the parameter vector $\mathbf{a}$, i.e. $b=f(\mathbf{a})$.

According to the Wikipedia article about the Fisher information (at least I think so), we would have:
\begin{align}
\mathbf{I}_{\mathbf{a}}=\mathbf{J}^\mathrm{T}I_b\mathbf{J},
\end{align}
where $\mathbf{J}$ is the Jacobian of our function $f(.)$. Equivalently, I think it should hold that $\mathbf{I}_{\mathbf{a}}^{-1} \mathbf{J}^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{J}$ is the $2\times2$ identity matrix that is scaled by $\frac{1}{I_b}$.

In my coding example however, the matrix is no scaled identity matrix and nothing really adds up so I think there might be something wrong with my approach. I would consequently be very grateful for any kind of help, tutorial or references that you could provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to wikipedia, ${I}_{{b}}=\mathbf{J}^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{I_a}\mathbf{J}$ where $\bf J$ is a 2x1 column matrix. Further, $J_{11} = \dfrac{\partial a_1}{\partial b}$ and $J_{21} = \dfrac{\partial a_2}{\partial b}$

Comment: Which makes way more sense, but what do I misunderstand about the article? They write that $\theta$ is a function of $\eta$, i.e. $\theta(\eta)$ and in this case supposedly $I_\eta = J^T I_\theta J$ where $J$ is the Jacobian of $\theta$.
So did the Wikipedia article mess up or am I just too stupid to understand it correctly? The book I looked into just formulates it for the Cramer Rao bound, i.e. they say: $I_b^{-1}=\mathbf{J}\mathbf{I}_{\mathbf{a}}^{-1} \mathbf{J}^\mathrm{T} $, which is yet another formulation than yours.

Comment: @J.Doe: yeah, I do agree, I was confused too when I first encountered this notation. Nevertheless, your approach is also correct. You can crosscheck if your Jacobian computation is right or not.